# Internal error when doing JUnit with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

When I try to do JUnit test with my Eclipse Indigo IDE (on Ubuntu 10.10), I get this error shown in a popup window:

```
An internal error has occurred.
org.eclipse.ui.internal.ErrorViewPart cannot be cast to org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsoleView
```

Although there is no problem with the JUnit test, the error just shows up. Any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at either workspace/.metadata/.logs or configuration/.log files. If those are not conclusive it is better to restart the eclipse and see how it works. If the problem persists and if you get some clue about it from the log, then that is only the way to go.